# How do you type on a new line in interactive ruby without inputting the data?

Tags: ruby

In Python's IDLE if you press shift+Enter you can begin typing on a newline, what is the Ruby equivalent?

I am trying to pass arguments to a function using a hash argument and would like to be able to span each hash item on its own line. How can I do this in interactive Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html):

> An input is executed when it is syntactically complete.

Entering incomplete expressions results in "multi-line mode", e.g. starting a hash with <kbd>{</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> {
irb(main):002:1*   foo: 1,
irb(main):003:1*   bar: 2
irb(main):004:1> }
#=> {:foo=>1, :bar=>2}
irb(main):005:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out! I need to separate each argument with a comma.